# Get a subset of data from one row of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Let's say I have a dataframe df with columns 'A', 'B', 'C'
Now I just want to extract row 2 of df and only columns 'B' and 'C'. What is the most efficient way to do that?

Can you please tell me why df.ix[2, ['B', 'C']] didn't work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), list('xyz'), list('ABC'))
df

   A  B  C
x  0  1  2
y  3  4  5
z  6  7  8
```

If you want to maintain a dataframe

```
df.loc[df.index[[1]], ['B', 'C']]

   B  C
y  4  5
```

If you want a series

```
df.loc[df.index[1], ['B', 'C']]

B    4
C    5
Name: y, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell me why this didn't work df.ix[2, ['B', 'C']]?

Comment: @PythonEdu `ix` has always been a bit confusing and is why it is now deprecated in pandas 0.20.  It was confusing because it tried to infer what you meant.  Was that integer a position or a label?  Sometimes the meaning of `df.ix[2, ['B', 'C']]` could be ambiguous.  Or depend on the `df`. So to answer your question.  I don't know why `ix` didn't work because it depends on your specific dataframe.  But let's not bother because it's deprecated and you shouldn't be using it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

`row_2 = df[['B', 'C']].iloc[1]`

OR

`# Convert column to 2xN vector, grab row 2
row_2 = list(df[['B', 'C']].apply(tuple, axis=1))[1]`